# MissingMetadataException release mode UWP 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, .net-native

My app works fine in debug mode, however not in release mode

Error:

```
SRCSRV: The module '<Embedded module of SharedLibrary.dll>' does not contain source server information.
SRCSRV: The module '<Embedded module of SharedLibrary.dll>' does not contain source server information.
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException' in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
Additional information: Arg_InvokeMethodMissingMetadata, System.EventHandler. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485
SRCSRV: The module '<Embedded module of SharedLibrary.dll>' does not contain source server information.
```

I found a lot of information about this problem including stackoverflow
[Stackoverflow question about same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176696/missingmetadataexception-when-building-uwp-app-with-net-native)

[MissingMetadataException troubleshooter](http://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html)

The problem for me is that i don't get the full information like in ex1. "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCacheOptions" in additional information.

I get "Arg_InvokeMethodMissingMetadata, System.EventHandler"

I tried the add missing types into my Default.rd.xaml of the X64 release map.

Attempts:

```
<Application>
<!--
  An Assembly element with Name="*Application*" applies to all assemblies in
  the application package. The asterisks are not wildcards.
-->
<Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />


<!-- Add your application specific runtime directives here. -->

    <Type Name="System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Assembly Name=" Mscorlib.dll" Dynamic="Required All" />
</Application>
```

Attempt 2

```
<Type>
  <MethodInstantiation Arguments="System.EventHandler" Dynamic="Required" />
</Type>
```

Am i missing something of information?

Comment: Hello! I work on the .NET Native runtime and compiler team. If you're still having issues with this, we'd love to help out. Please email us at dotnetnative@microsoft.com and we can figure out how best to proceed. Once we figure it out I'm always happy to post the answer back here! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response.I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @MattWhilden ever resolve this one?